# Return generic type after parsing an Integer from a String

Tags: java, casting

I am trying to write a method that gets an object from a database. This method must be able to specify what class that object expected to be (like: `get("some.key", Integer.class)` will return an integer).
However, if the expected type is an integer, and our value is a string, I would like it to cast that string to an integer and return that.
My current code looks like this:

```java
public <T> T get(String key, Class<T> type) {
    Object element = ...;
    if (type == Integer.class && element instanceof String) return Integer.parseInt((String) element);
    return element;
}
```

However, my IDE is giving me an error: when returning `Integer.parseInt((String) element)`, the method expects a return type of type `T`, but I am returning an Integer, which in that case is type `T`, but it won't accept this.

I have tried to cast it like so: `(T) Integer.parseInt((String) element)`, but my IDE says that those are inconvertible types.

How can I make it so that this method will return a valid object of type `T` after parsing the Integer?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast your result to `T` using the `Class` instance you are passed.

```
public <T> T get(String key, Class<T> type) {
    Object element = ...;
    if (type == Integer.class && element instanceof String) element = Integer.parseInt((String) element);
    return type.cast(element);
}
```